# ListBoxItem selected property

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm using the `ListBoxItem` in xaml in cs and I need to know if there is a property in the object that said if it's clicked(marked).

Is there any property? If so what is the name?

Answer (score 2):

There is a property `IsSelected` on the `ListBoxItem` class that returns whether it is selected or not. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.isselected(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx) shows the other properties and methods of the class.